# Create an Object from a GUI - Java

Tags: java, swing

I have this simple class `Cat` to describe the features of a cat:

```
public class Cat {

  private String name;
  private String race;
  private String colour;
  private int age;

  public Cat(String name, String race, String colour, int age) {
    this.name=name;
    this.race=race;
    this.colour=colour;
    this.age=age;
  }      

  public String getRace() {
      return race;
  }
  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }
  public String getColour() {
      return colour;
  }
  public int getAge() {
      return age;
  }

}
```

I also have a `CatDemo` class that creates an instance of a Frame class (that extends JFrame) from which one can insert cat's information:

```
public class CatDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.setVisible(true); 
    }

}
```

This is my GUI:

[image]

When one presses `OK` I have to create an instance of `Cat` class (I have to create a `Cat` object with the features inserted in the blanks of the GUI).
It's easy to create this instance inside `actionPerformed` method:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Cat c = new Cat(textField.getText(),textField_1.getText(),
                        textField_2.getText(),Integer.parseInt(textField_3.getText())); 
    }
```

But now I need my Cat object to make something else. How can I use `c` from `CatDemo` class (where there is main)?

Comment: Just declare `Cat c;` outside of your method and inside of your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend Frame.

```
public class MyFrame extends Frame {
    public Cat buildCatFromInputFields() {
        ...
        return cat;
    }
}
```

Also what you need to understand is, that you are leaving your main thread, when entering the AWT world (with that frame).
What i mean is, that after you call *f.setVisible(true)*, your main method and the main thread end!
Thus it would be completely advisable to just use your cat inside your ActionHandler methods (like *actionPerformed()*).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a public static list of cats in your main program and from your Frame, when a user presses OK, you can do something like

```
CatDemo.cats.Add(new Cat(name, race, color, age));
```